# How can I create my new own extension?

Tags: c

Since there are many extension for Databases (for e.g.. mdb) which uses their own application. How can I create my own extension, Let assume I made application for Databases in  C.Now I need that my application only use my extension such as .deb or .dbe etc, How can I do that.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I.e in Windows extensions are managed in the registry.

Comment: I am using Mac @SevenBits

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's pretty complex. Extensions are managed by UTIs, and the system scans application bundles to see which files they can open. Your app declares what it can open through .plist files. I'd read up in the Apple docs for more info, this is well documented.

Comment: @SevenBits So Please tell me How Windows manage extensions?

Comment: A file extension is paired with a program in the registry, and when you double-click on a file of that type, Windows opens the associated program.

Comment: Can you please tell me any reference to learn more about Registry?

Comment: This is way too broad, i'd suggest you get started and come back when you have a specific issue with your implementation.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I don't know How to start??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes..!!! You can

To make your own extension you need to follow these steps

- Choose first an extension (preferably a 3 letter extension like `.EXE`, `.DLL`, `.OUT`, `.MP3`, `.AVI`... ).
- Then choose your encoding style, this means you need to encode your data in a different manner that distinguishes previous styles for example in `.CSV` or (**Comma Separated Values**) file format words are stored in plain text format but separated by a 
  comma
  (**,**).
- Finally you need a procedure that can be used to decode your new file extension. which should be able to reverse the encoding process.

> Feel free to ask further queries...

Answer (score 0):

A file extension is not a garantee the file follows a certain format.

If you wish so, you can save your files as database.monkey . 
Then, you can make your program open the file with a file explorer using a filter such as " *.monkey".

Comment: I want that my file  only open by my created application not by other application.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. A workaround might be to save the data in a cryptic way so that every program can read it but only your program can understand it.